# How long a deleted answer will be seen for owner and is there a way to remove it immediately after deleting

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I have deleted my answer for a question with others comment, and for two days it is showing in question. Is there a way to delete it permanently after deleting.

Comment: It's showing only for you (try logging out and viewing it). Users with >10K reputation also have the ability to view deleted posts.

Comment: @DavidRobinson, how long do users with >10K reputation get to see the deleted post? Indefinitely? Just curious as well. Thanks.

Comment: @daOnlyBG Indefinitely.

Answer (score 11):

As soon as you post something on any Stack Exchange site the content is stored in the databases and only soft-deleted.

As long as you have a link to your own post you can see and edit the content (if it was not locked). You can search for your deleted posts by using the [`deleted:1` search operator if you have 10K or more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270562/158100).

If you have a recent post (posted less than 60 days ago) that is deleted you can find those posts on your profile by following the link at the bottom of your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2986598/joachin-joseph?tab=questions) or [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2986598/joachin-joseph?tab=answers) list.

Any user with more than 10,000 reputation can see deleted posts if they know the URL of the post. They can also vote to undelete such posts if warranted.

[Moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) can see and search for all deleted posts of all users with the `deleted:1` operator and they can see the deleted posts on your profile.

In the rare circumstance that a revision of a post needs to be deleted, you can flag for a moderator and they will ask an SE employee to remove the revision. As this is a non-automated operation your flag will be declined if the damage done is already irreversible. Having your username/password removed is kind-of useless as Google probably already fetched that data.

Comment: That being said, I've never had a flag rejected asking for credentials to be removed from the post itself / revision history

Comment: @Rob that's... weird.